# Event Listener's Parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, addeventlistener

TypeScript's type definition file for ES6 (`lib.es6.d.ts`), defines addEventListener on the window object as follows:

```
addEventListener<K extends keyof WindowEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: Window, ev: WindowEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;
```

As seen, it defines the listener as having two parameters: `this` and `ev`.

As we know, `ev` is the event object and `this` is the DOM element the `event` was fired from. We also know that the browser automatically passes these arguments into the event listener when the event fires.

**Question**

When I create a handler and check the length of its arguments, I am told there is only one:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', myHandler2);

function myHandler2() {
    // Output of the below is: args length: 1, arg 1: [object KeyboardEvent]
    console.log('args length: ' + arguments.length + ', arg 1: ' + arguments[0]);
}
```

Thus, I am wondering, why is the method definition telling me there are two parameters, when in fact there is only one?

**Side Note**

This is not specific to addEventListener. The `onclick` method, for example, has the following type-definition:

```
onclick: (this: HTMLElement, ev: MouseEvent) => any;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the Typescript docs on functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html):

> [When declaring a function,] you can provide an explicit `this` parameter. `this` parameters are fake parameters that come first in the parameter list of a function.

Note the description of `this` as a "fake" parameter. In JavaScript, `this` is an implicit parameter for functions. Its value is determined by [how the function is called](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), and it cannot be provided as a positional argument when calling a function. TypeScript works around this by pretending that it is the first positional argument (hence calling it "fake").

If you are unfamiliar with `this` in JavaScript functions, you may find it valuable to read [*Understanding JavaScript Function Invocation and "this"*](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/).

Comment: Thank you. I am comfortable with `this` in JS, but not in TS. So, where in JS we have to use `call`, `apply` or `bind`, to change the `this`-value from its default, in TS we can just pass it as a parameter in any function call?

Comment: No, `this` still behaves the same way. See [this example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20greet(this%3A%20String%2C%20person%3A%20String)%3A%20String%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this%20%2B%20'%20'%20%2B%20person%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Agreet.call('Ahoy'%2C%20'Alice')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Agreet('Hello'%2C%20'Bob')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20sayHello%20%3D%20greet.bind('Hello')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AsayHello('Bob')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A): `greet` cannot be called without having a `this` value bound.

Comment: Actually, I see that my comment above was incorrect. If we cannot access it, why should it be explicitly provided? And why is it included in the type definition for our event listeners?

Comment: The function *can* access `this`, it's just not provided as a positional argument.

Comment: Sorry for the slightly unclear formulation, I meant that the function cannot access the `this`-value from the parameter. I mean, what is the point of defining `this` as a parameter in the function, if it does not alter JavaScript's normal behavior for `this`

Comment: Oh, perhaps specifying `this` as a first function parameter, forces the caller to invoke the function in a way that specifies the `this`  value. So you would have to use call, apply or bind, or define it inside an object and do `myObj.myFunc()`? That's what your example code demonstrates too?

Comment: Correct. Even though `this` is special, it's still important for your function to declare its type just like any other parameter (if your function uses it).

Answer (score 1):

`this` doesn't show in the argument list as it is not really a parameter, just a reference to the calling object. In the event listener example `this` refers to the window object.

> this parameters are fake parameters that come first in the parameter list of a function:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html